# Why one dynamic value can be converted to other without casting and the other one fails?

Tags: dart

```
final dList = <dynamic> [];
final List<String> sList1 = dList;  // fails (can't implicitly cast)
final sList2 = dList.cast<String>(); // works (needs manual casting)

dynamic dString = '';
final String sString1 = dString; // works
final sString2 = dString as String; // works
```

You can see the comments in the code part what I am talking about, it is difficult to point out the piece of code here in writing part, so I added them in the code part.

`List` fails to convert but other types like `bool`, `int`, `String` works with internal casting.

Comment: Check this https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that `dList` is a `List<dynamic>`. The type `dynamic` is a top type (a supertype of all other types), and it's reified (so you can test it at run time, as opposed to Java where type arguments are erased at run time). With `cast` you are creating a new object, instance of `List<String>`, so it's allowed to be the value of a variable of that type.

With `dString` you already have an instance of type `String` (because `''` evaluates to such an instance), so the cast just verifies that this is indeed a `String`.

You can never use a cast in Dart to obtain an object whose type is different from the starting point, it will only check the type of the existing object (and confirm that the type is as required, or throw).